# How can I  get all constants of a type by reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, constants

How can I get all constants of any type using reflection?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2003/02/20/2708.aspx

Answer (score 371, accepted):

Though it's an old code:

```
private FieldInfo[] GetConstants(System.Type type)
{
    ArrayList constants = new ArrayList();

    FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = type.GetFields(
        // Gets all public and static fields

        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | 
        // This tells it to get the fields from all base types as well

        BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

    // Go through the list and only pick out the constants
    foreach(FieldInfo fi in fieldInfos)
        // IsLiteral determines if its value is written at 
        //   compile time and not changeable
        // IsInitOnly determines if the field can be set 
        //   in the body of the constructor
        // for C# a field which is readonly keyword would have both true 
        //   but a const field would have only IsLiteral equal to true
        if(fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly)
            constants.Add(fi);           

    // Return an array of FieldInfos
    return (FieldInfo[])constants.ToArray(typeof(FieldInfo));
}
```

[Source](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2003/02/20/2708.aspx)

You can easily convert it to cleaner code using generics and LINQ:

```
private List<FieldInfo> GetConstants(Type type)
{
    FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
         BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

    return fieldInfos.Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly).ToList();
}
```

Or with one line:

```
type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static |
               BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
    .Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly).ToList();
```

Comment: *My +1* was before i even passed 2nd line ..i noticed you're going through every step with its ...intended-by-design purpose... ! this is **SO** important when one needs to learn from it. i wish every one with your experience would do as you did here .

Comment: I'm not sure about the assertions with regards to IsLiteral and IsInitOnly. On testing it would seem that for static readonly properties IsLiteral is always false - so IsLiteral is the only flag you need to check to find constants and you can ignore IsInitOnly. I tried with different field types (e.g. String, Int32) to see if this made any difference but it did not.

Comment: Also, to get the value of the const from the FieldInfo, use GetRawConstantValue().

Comment: @MarkWatts is right. May be the behaviour changed since this was posted. In any case documentation of `IsLiteral` says `if its value is written at compile time` and that is true only for constants, which is how it is behaving now (tested as of .NET 4.5.2)

Answer (score 101):

If you would like to get the *values* of all constants of a specific type, from the target type, here is an extension method (extending some of the answers on this page):

```
public static class TypeUtilities
{
    public static List<T> GetAllPublicConstantValues<T>(this Type type)
    {
        return type
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
            .Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly && fi.FieldType == typeof(T))
            .Select(x => (T)x.GetRawConstantValue())
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Then for a class like this

```
static class MyFruitKeys
{
    public const string Apple = "apple";
    public const string Plum = "plum";
    public const string Peach = "peach";
    public const int WillNotBeIncluded = -1;
}
```

You can obtain the `string` constant values like this:

```
List<string> result = typeof(MyFruitKeys).GetAllPublicConstantValues<string>();
//result[0] == "apple"
//result[1] == "plum"
//result[2] == "peach"
```

Comment: Why not this: `.Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly).Select(x => x.GetRawConstantValue()).OfType<T>().ToList();`?

Answer (score 25):

As Type extensions:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetConstants(this Type type)
    {
        var fieldInfos = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

        return fieldInfos.Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetConstantsValues<T>(this Type type) where T : class
    {
        var fieldInfos = GetConstants(type);

        return fieldInfos.Select(fi => fi.GetRawConstantValue() as T);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously this is if your constants on a type are all strings ;-)

Comment: Why not (a) make the methods generic, (b) make the methods return `IEnumerable<T>` instead of an `IList`?

Comment: @WaiHaLee - Done :-).  Though obviously it still assumes all the types of consts on the class in question are of type T.

Answer (score 4):

Use `property.GetConstantValue()` to get value.

Comment: That may well be the case when you *have* the property - but *how* do you first get the property?

Comment: In .Net 4.5 it's: `GetRawConstantValue()`

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Constants
{
    public class InputType
    {
        public const string DOCUMENTPHOTO = "document-photo";
        public const string SELFIEPHOTO = "selfie-photo";
        public const string SELFIEVIDEO = "selfie-video";
        public static List<string> Domain { get { return typeof(Constants.InputType).GetAllPublicConstantValues<string>(); } }
    }
    public class Type
    {
        public const string DRIVINGLICENSE = "driving-license";
        public const string NATIONALID = "national-id";
        public const string PASSPORT = "passport";
        public const string PROOFOFRESIDENCY = "proof-of-residency";
        public static List<string> Domain { get { return typeof(Constants.Type).GetAllPublicConstantValues<string>(); } }
    }
    public class Page
    {
        public const string FRONT = "front";
        public const string BLACK = "back";
        public static List<string> Domain { get { return typeof(Constants.Page).GetAllPublicConstantValues<string>(); } }
    }
    public class FileType
    {
        public const string FRONT = "selfie";
        public const string BLACK = "video";
        public const string DOCUMENT = "document";
        public const string MEDIA = "media";
        public const string CAPTCHA = "captcha";
        public const string DIGITALSIGNATURE = "digitalSignature";
        public static List<string> Domain { get { return typeof(Constants.FileType).GetAllPublicConstantValues<string>(); } }
    }
}

public static class TypeUtilities
{
    public static List<T> GetAllPublicConstantValues<T>(this Type type)
    {
        return type
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
            .Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly && fi.FieldType == typeof(T))
            .Select(x => (T)x.GetRawConstantValue())
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Use: var inputTypeDomain = Constants.InputType.Domain;

Comment: Im not following this - what is it doing?

Comment: It appears to just have a copy/paste of BCA's answer