# Loop all the constants in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, constants

I want to loop all the constant variable from a static class. For example

```
public class SiteDetails
{
    public const string SD_MAIN_TRUST = "MainTrust";
    public const string SD_MAIN_COLLEGE = "MainCollege";
}
```

I want to read constants one by one to check for match.

Comment: Are all the constants effectively related? Sounds like you should use an enum instead.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261824/how-can-i-get-all-constants-of-a-type-by-reflection/34228649#34228649

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get all public static fields of your type:

```
Type type = typeof(SiteDetails);
var flags = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public;
var fields = type.GetFields(flags); // that will return all fields of any type
```

You can add `IsLiteral` filtering if you want to check only constants.

```
var fields = type.GetFields(flags).Where(f => f.IsLiteral);
```

Then check if value of any field equals to your value:

```
string value = "MainCollege"; // your value
bool match = fields.Any(f => value.Equals(f.GetValue(null)));
```

Comment: Getfields() is not returning the constants. I want to read all the constants one by one.

Comment: @Nathiya I don't think you have tried my code. You have static literal fields, which should be read with GetFields() method

Comment: i have tried your code just now it is giving zero fields.
 var flags = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public;
                var field1s = classType.GetFields(flags);

Comment: @Nathiya just verified - it gives me two fields `SD_MAIN_TRUST` and `SD_MAIN_COLLEGE`. Make sure you are using exactly same code as I provided. Also make sure your real class has name `SiteDetails` and it really contains fields.

Comment: Now i am getting the result after including BindingFlags.Instance im getting the result. In order to check the fields how to get all the fields using loop?

Comment: @Nathiya if you are getting results with BindingFlags.Instance then your code differs from question. Constants are static. Also I don't understand why you need explicit loop if you want to check for match. But of course you can `foreach(FieldInfo field in fields) { ... }`

Answer (score 4):

You can *enumerate* constants by using *Linq*:

```
  foreach(FieldInfo info in typeof(SiteDetails).GetFields().Where(x => x.IsStatic && x.IsLiteral)) {
    // info is the constant description with
    // info.Name       - constant's name  (e.g. "SD_MAIN_TRUST")
    // info.GetValue() - constant's value (e.g. "MainTrust")
    ...
  }
```