# Can I restrict a C# function to accept string literals only?

Tags: c#, gettext, type-constraints

In order to allow extracting all translatable messages from the source code, we want to use a specific 'semantic' `Message` class.  Only Messages can be presented to the UI.  This way we want to prevent too many untranslated string ending up in the UI.

But an occurence like `Message.Create("a" + x)` can not be extracted by the gettext extraction engine.

So is there a way in C# to assure that my function (`GetText._` or the like) is only called with string literals?

Or should I revert to preprocessing somehow?  Are there any libraries/tools that can do this out there?

Comment: As opposed to what exactly?

Comment: @TheGeneral I'll elaborate on the 'why'

Comment: What is the signature of your function? Your question only makes sense if you have *object* as function parameter, otherwise just accept *String*.

Comment: Maybe you should use enums, at least your weird requirement is clearly a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is clearly a xy-problem but OP hasn't provided enough details to suggest a different approach

Comment: What still baffles me is why you would want to single out string **literals** only. How is the *"Why"* elaboration coming along?

Comment: Are you looking for a compile time restriction? If you are, the answer is no.

Comment: @InBetween compile time would be great.  Load time or run time are possible, too.  AST manipulation, ... anything that does the job.

Comment: Possible dupe, at least related, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035933/check-if-a-string-is-a-literal-string-known-at-compile-time).

Comment: "_extracting all translatable messages_" how about storing these messages in Resource file? You have them all in one place and translation requires changing only 1 line of code...

Comment: @FCin: See the comments on my answer. The OP appears to dislike the centralized approach :(

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the language to support an argument having to be a string literal, no. I think that would be an odd language "feature", personally.

What I would advise instead is to create a `MessageTemplate` class or something like that, and change your method to accept a `MessageTemplate` parameter.

The `MessageTemplate` class can then have a specific set of instances, which would contain all the strings you need. For example:

```
public sealed class MessageTemplate
{
    public static MessageTemplate InvalidFilter { get; } =
        new MessageTemplate("invalid_filter");

    public static MessageTemplate Success { get; } =
        new MessageTemplate("success");

    public string Name { get; }

    private MessageTemplate(string name) => Name = name;
}
```

Then the method calls would be like this:

```
Message.Create(MessageTemplate.Success);
```

Advantages:

- The valid strings are all in a single place, rather than scattered through the codebase
- The calling code can use a useful name (e.g. "Success") even if the underlying string name is less useful (e.g. "x"), which makes it easier to read
- You can pass `MessageTemplate` references around safely, knowing that they *are* message templates rather than just arbitrary strings

---

If you *really* wanted to only accept string literals, your best bet would probably be to create an attribute for this purpose, and then write a Roslyn analyzer. That would check every method invocation, and validate that if the parameter had the attribute, the argument was a string literal.

Personally I think that has the undesirable effect of scattering these magic, brittle string constants all over the codebase, but it's the closest you'll get to the *exact* behavior you've requested. It will only have an effect when building with Roslyn, of course.

Comment: *I think that would be an odd language "feature", personally* - exercise to the user: use Roslyn to alter the C# language so `string` literals *are* different somehow...

Comment: @Rawling: I suspect it wouldn't be too hard to write a Roslyn analyzer so that you could add an attribute to a method parameter, and then check all calls to the method, raising a warning if the corresponding argument wasn't a string literal. I prefer the answer I've given here for this situation, of course :)

Comment: This is obviously a better approach compared to scattering calls with magic strings all over your code but its still punting the problem. At the end, nothing, except code review or some preprocessing tool, is assuring you that whatever message your helper class is returning is in fact a string literal.

Comment: Instead of trying to enforce this weird rule I would look at a different solution to the problem. What happens when one of the messages has to be written based on a condition?

Comment: @InBetween: My understanding of the problem is not the fact that it's a string literal which is important, so much as that it's only a fixed set of strings that will be accepted. The template class enforces that only that fixed set of strings is used. Yes, that class needs reviewing to make sure the strings are correct, but that's all.

Comment: @FCin: Then you pick one `MessageTemplate` or other based on the condition - easy.

Comment: ... why move all translatable messages into a single spot?  That would couple the whole code base to a single, often-changing class.

Comment: @xtofl: It only needs to change when a new message is added - at which point you'll be changing other code anyway to use the message. The alternative of scattering magic string values around the codebase sounds *much* worse to me. How do you protect against typos in that scenario? Note that putting them all in one place makes it really easy to find all the existing messages as well, encouraging increased consistency: it makes it easy to reuse an existing message instead of creating a new one.

Comment: That statement goes for any coupled code.  A message added to X requires a change in A and a recompile of an unrelated Y.

The gathering of scattered messages is what `gettext` has solved 20 years ago, which is the reason I want to try reusing it.  It solves most i18n problems, which 'just' a resource file does not.

Comment: @xtofl: I think we'll have to agree to differ on what makes for maintainable code and idiomatic C#. If you really want to stick with potentially-slightly-inconsistent string literals all over the place, I suggest you write a Roslyn analyzer, but I'd still recommend this approach instead.

Comment: @xtofl Storing data in Resource files will not require recompilation. "_That would couple the whole code base_". Not if you abstract access to Resource files with custom class, e.g. `ResourceRepository`. Now you have interface dependency `IResourceRepository` which exposes `SetCulture(...)`, `GetString(...)`, etc. Going against the language and building confusing structures will quickly create a lot of code to maintain and understand. Simple class with abstraction is great for simple/easy to understand separation.

Comment: @FCin: If the OP were to use resource files and the generated resource code (which is the only way it would be nice and compile-time safe) it would require a rebuild to pick up new resource names. Personally I don't see that as being a significant problem though.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Why would anyone want to change variable names at runtime? If we are talking about values then they can be changed/added without recompilation, more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/packaging-and-deploying-resources-in-desktop-apps)

Comment: @FCin: I don't see where variable names come in. The point is that if you add a new message, you need to add that to the resource file (or the `MessageTemplate` in my answer). You regenerate the code, and then you can refer to that message in a compile-time-safe way. I'm not talking about adding a new translation for an existing message (that wouldn't require recompilation) - I'm talking about adding a completely new message. I fail to see how you'd use a new message without recompilation, but in a safe way.