# Get properties returning a constant value

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to obtain all properties from a class returning constant values through reflection. I have [seen this to be working for const fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10261848/), obviously, but not for properties.

Is there a way to determine if a property is actually returning a constant value?

Sample:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Fox => GetSomething(); // should not be returned
    public string Foz {get;} // should not be returned
    public string Bar {get;set;} // should not be returned

    public string Baz => "hello there"; // SHOULD be returned
}
```

Any effort so far failed. I tried to call `GetConstantValue()` on the property, but that throws an exception ("InvalidOperationException: 'Literal value was not found.'"). It doesn't seem to be the right method to do this.

Comment: Exception? SQL exception? Overflow Exception?

Comment: Do you hit the set block? In other words: place a break point inside it to make sure it is hit

Comment: @efekctive See the update. Not sure what you mean with "how you hit it". It is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Well, if you don't hit the set block of a property how do you expect it to have a value? First make sure it even executes

Comment: That is totally irrelevant as said. This is just a mock of a much more complex object. Setting a value is not an issue here.

Comment: As you please. My bad

Comment: I'm not sure what you want is achievable through reflection. A property getter is just a parameterless method, which returns an object of an specific type... what that method does is not in the metadata obtained via reflection, as far as I know

Comment: Get a list of properties that need some work for a specific programming task I have been given on X million lines. I can narrow doen the properties that need changing very quickly with this option.

Comment: I do not think this will be possible without inspecting the IL of the property getter. There is no assembly metadata that specifies whether the return value is constant. When you use the `=> X` syntax the compiler simply generates a getter body that does `return X`. You will have to examine the IL to determine whether the body does anything more than return a value that does not depend on any external factors. This will get tricky.

Comment: That is what I thought too, hoped there was anything that could help here @TypeIA

Comment: To simplify your code: get { return "CONsTANT";} set{....} No need to to anything else

Comment: I agree with @TypeIA even though in code the property returns a string literal and it is a read-only.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getconstantvalue(v=vs.110).aspx. This document does not state that it is returning the Property value. If you use GetValue(Foo instance) works like a charm. Read your docs first

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to do this strange thing? This has the smell of an XY problem.

Comment: Yes, it is Eric. It was an idea to do a quick workaround to diagnose some (partial) class that holds automatically generated translation entries (file A) and manual entries needed to go in the automated process (file B). This class is derived in a next layer, so I had like to go over all those entries and filter out those I have entered manually. For now, I will just try to parse the C# file myself.