# Loop through strings in a class

Tags: c#, .net, loops, for-loop

I have a class in C#:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static class Animals
    {
        public const string theDog = "dog";
        public const string theCat = "cat";
    }
}
```

And I want to loop through the "assignments" of that class (not the properties). And I want to get the values without having to 
explicitly specify the property. I'm trying to do this because I have a class of a a lot of constants and I want to add them to a list.

So, my desired output / code would look something like this:

```
foreach (string animal in Constants.Animals)
{
       Console.WriteLine(animal)
}
```

Output:

```
dog
cat
```

I have tried reflection, but that only gives me the property.

Comment: Show your reflection code and perhaps someone can help you get the value you're wanting

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261824/how-can-i-get-all-constants-of-a-type-by-reflection

Comment: you have written a sample of for loop, but for that to work you will need a foreach loop. or u need to change the syntax to for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using *Reflection*:

```
  using System.Reflection;

  ...

  var animals = typeof(Constants.Animals)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(field => field.IsLiteral)
    .Where(field => field.FieldType == typeof(String))
    .Select(field => field.GetValue(null) as String);

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, animals));
```

Outcome:

```
  dog
  cat
```

if you want a loop

```
  foreach (string animal in animals) {
    Console.WriteLine(animal); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

See this Reflection:-
GetValue will give you the value.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyinfo in typeof(yourClass).GetProperties())
        {
           if(propertyinfo !=null){
            var valueOfField=propertyinfo.GetValue(yourobject);
            var fieldname = propertyinfo.Name;

            if (valueOfField!=null && fieldname != null)
            {
              string data=fieldname +"="+valueOfField
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: that's true @HimBromBeere

Comment: The `propertyInfo != null`-check is pointless in your case, as you´re accessing `propertyInfo.Name` before which causes an NRE **before** you even check for null.