# Using static type member to ensure type-safety in a non-static class

Tags: c#

I have a static class defined like this:

```
public static class JobStatus
{ 
    public const string Completed = "Completed";
    public const string Failed = "Failed";
    public const string Stopped = "Stopped";
}
```

(this is actually an external library, so can't change this)

In my non-static class I want a member of that class to ensure that you can only declare it of that "type"

```
public class JobOutput
{
    public string Output { get; set; }

    public string OutputError { get; set; }

    public JobStatus JobStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Error: 'JobStatus': static types cannot be used as return types / 'JobStatus': static types cannot be used as parameters

Yeye I know your eyes are bleeding, but I hope you get the point - how can I ensure and achieve a form of type-safety for my JobStatus property?

Comment: Do you want to ensure that your `JobStatus` property can only have those `string` values defined in the static `JobStatus` class?

Comment: Why JobStatus has to be static?

Comment: @dymanoid yep exactly

Comment: @TimSchmelter can't change it, using the class from another library

Comment: I also tried defining JobOutput class and its members as static, same result.

Comment: At face value, this feels like a good candidate for an `enum`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650080/how-to-get-c-sharp-enum-description-from-value

Comment: Do you need *type* safety (impossible with static types) or are you really trying to achieve *value* safety? My answer below would ensure value safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap `JobStatus` to make it "type safe" but it looks like a bit of an overkill:

```
public sealed class JobStatusWrapper
{
     public static readonly JobStatusWrapper Completed 
         = new JobStatusWrapper(JobStatus.Completed);

     public static readonly JobStatusWrapper Failed
         = new JobStatusWrapper(JobStatus.Failed);

     public static readonly JobStatusWrapper Stopped
         = new JobStatusWrapper(JobStatus.Stopped);

     private readonly string description;
     private JobStatusWrapper(string description) {
         Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(description));
         this.description = description; }

     public static implicit operator string(JobStatusWrapper status)
         => status.description;
}
```

And now you'd use it:

```
public class JobOutput
{
    //...
    public JobStatusWrapper JobStatus { get; set; }
}
```

And there is no way to pass in or get a `JobStatusWrapper` that doesn't have one of the underlying values defined in `JobStatus` (except `null`). Also, the implicit operator makes the wrapper usable anywhere the `JobStatus` options are.

Comment: Thanks for the input! learned some new stuff there. But yes as @codecaster said the library could change, so i'd be even greater if it were dynamic. I don't think it will change though, so might be wasted effort. In anycase thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because all `JobStatus` does is contain some members who hold *strings*. So you'll have to define your `JobStatus` property as a string as well.

There's no compile-time safety for strings, it could've been an enum instead.

You could add a method `SetJobStatus(string status)` to your `JobOutput` class and make `JobStatus`'s setter private. Then in that method, you check (using reflection) whether the `status` string is present in one of the static class `JobStatus`'s public const fields. Or you could implement the same in the setter.

See [How can I  get all constants of a type by reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261824/how-can-i-get-all-constants-of-a-type-by-reflection) for information on how to do that. But that's not compile-time safety, but runtime.

Comment: yes that was also the approach I would go for if I can't get compile-time safety - was hoping though :)