# c# get List<string> from class

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-9.0

I have a class with const strings,
is there any way to get all const strings of these class to a List ?

```
public class Permissions
{
public const string AccessHomePage = "AccessHomePage";
public const string AccessAdminPage = "AccessAdminPage";
...
}
```

To add an admin user all permission at once would be easier
to get a list directy of all strings in the class...

`List<string> allPermissions =`

Would be really nice...

Comment: You can use reflection to get all constant fields in your class

Comment: There is no straight forward way to achieve this. You need to use reflection. If you can modify this class then you should expose a property from this class with a list of all the strings.

Comment: Maybe an enum with flags attribute would be a better solution? If you really want to use string constants, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261824/how-can-i-get-all-constants-of-a-type-by-reflection

Comment: @SomeBody yep this would be the right so to look up, coudn't find it since i wasn't aware of reflections...

Comment: NB: If your string values are always equal to the field name, you might as well use `public const string AccessHomePage = nameof(AccessHomePage);`, lest they might get "out of sync".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

**Given**

```
public class Permissions
{
   public const string AccessHomePage = "AccessHomePage";
   public const string AccessAdminPage = "AccessAdminPage";
}
```

**Example**

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetConstants<T>()
   => typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
      .Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(string) && x.IsLiteral && !x.IsInitOnly)
      .Select(x => x.GetValue(null) as string);
```

**Usage**

```
foreach (var item in GetConstants<Permissions>())
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Output**

```
AccessHomePage
AccessAdminPage
```

<sub>*Add Pepper and Salt to taste*</sub>

---

**Explanation**

`BindingFlags.Public`

> Specifies that public members are to be included in the search.

`BindingFlags.Static`

> Specifies that static members are to be included in the search.

`BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy`

> Specifies that public and protected static members up the hierarchy
> should be returned. Private static members in inherited classes are
> not returned. Static members include fields, methods, events, and
> properties. Nested types are not returned.

[`FieldInfo.IsInitOnly Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.isinitonly?view=net-5.0)

> Gets a value indicating whether the field can only be set in the body
> of the constructor.

[`FieldInfo.IsLiteral Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.isliteral?view=net-5.0)

> Gets a value indicating whether the value is written at compile time
> and cannot be changed.

Comment: This is purely depends on method usage, but I would add `f.FieldType == typeof(string)` check to `Where` clause. Just to be sure we don't get nulls in resulting array.

Comment: @Neistow good point